# Sending SMS with AT+ Commands using fopen()

Tags: php, sms, fopen, gsm

My gsm phone nokia 5530 is attached via usb on COM1 port. I am trying to send SMS but for some unknown reasons it is not working
**OS: windows 8.1**

```
<?php
exec("MODE COM1: BAUD=9600 PARITY=N DATA=8 STOP=1", $output, $retval);

print_r($retval);

$fp=fopen("COM1","r+");
if($fp){
    echo "COM1 port opened";
}
fwrite($fp,"AT+CMGF=1");
fwrite($fp,"AT+CMGS='03337954096','hi test message'");
fclose($fp);

?>
```

**Edit:**
Port is opening successfully however problem is in sending AT+ commands I guess

Comment: Added the code I forgot that @Guns

Comment: does it say it opened com1? If it DOESN'T open, then you should bail out instead of continuing on and trying to use an invalid file handle.

Comment: Yes it says port opened @MarcB

Comment: Have you tested connecting to the nokia via hyper terminal with these com port settings? Usually the best way to isolate connection settings issues. Sometimes you can connect but the phone/modem don't respond as expected. Try with Hyperterminal and send a simple AT to see if the phone echo's anything back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, what I did is open device manager see the modems and check for the com port number there! Moreoever sometimes port don't open for unknown reason then I restart my system and mobile then everything works like charm